# Can anyone identify these plots?

Tags: plotting

I need to produce some plots that look like these but I'm not sure what they are called in mathematica, can anyone identify them ?

[image: picture]

Update: I want to plot triples of the form (xvalue, yvalue, intensity) in a graph like that

Comment: Try `DensityPlot`!

Comment: DensityPlot appears to be for plotting functions, I have triples that I want to plot corresponding to (xvalue, yvalue, intensity)

Is there a function for doing this ?

Comment: It's probably `ArrayPlot`.  There's also MatrixPlot, Image, Graphics[Raster[...]], and ListDensityPlot (which can interpolate).  For triples you need ListDensityPlot or see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22191/12)

Answer (score 1):

It might be ListDensityPlot with an InterpolationOrder of 0 and a black/white ColorFunction

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa96b.jpg